# Creating an animation queue with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue

I'm trying to leverage the jquery queues in order to execute a series of functions in order. These "queued" functions, actually animate objects around on a page.

this was my original code for building my queue:

```
this.queue = function(fx, params) {
    this.animation_queue.push({fx: fx, params: params});
};
```

Then, once all functions are queued, I consume it something like this:

```
this.animate = function() {     
    for(var i=0; i<this.animation_queue.length; i++) {  
        this.animation_queue[i].fx.apply(this, [this.animation_queue[i].params]);
}};
```

The problem, obviously, that I ran into is that the queue elements were not executing properly. Though they did execute sequentially, because each function performed an animation, I actually need each queue elements to execute after the previous element's animation is finished.

I looked in to using jquery queues, like so:

```
this.queue = function(fx, params) {
    this.animation_queue.delay(500, 'animations');

    this.animation_queue.queue('animations', function(next) {
         next();

    });
};
```

But I'm not sure how I can call my functions as I did before, with the parameters.

Any suggestions about how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc:

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

You needn't worry about building and managing your own queue, the queue is managed by jQuery the moment you call queue on the element.

Here is a fiddle of their example that works just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/7GxwR/

So in order to feed your animations onto the queue, just create a single function that will stack all the animations on to the element in order and then call `.queue(...)` on the element to force it to execute in a queue.

If you're wanting to dynamically change / build the queue you would need to stop all animations, build the `runIt` function in the fiddle using a loop over an array of dynamic JSON objects that stores your animation parameters and timings, then call `showIt` and `runIt` as shown in the fiddle and example in the jQuery API.

The basic point being here, don't build your own queue / array, jQuery will do this for you if you call queue on an element with multiple effects applied already.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your fiddle link seems to be broken.